# In Attack of the Clones why didn't the Jedi simply disable Count Dooku's ship in order to prevent his escape?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Towards the end of *Star Wars: Attack of the Clones*, three Jedi try to keep Count Dooku from fleeing Geonosis. They battle him with lightsabers, but they don't think to simply slash his ship with their weapons and stop him from going anywhere. Why not?

Comment: Because then there would be no epic battle with lightsabers.

Comment: Seems like he could've found another ship.  The real question is why didn't they wreck his ship AND attack him.  We see Yoda lift an X-Wing in ESB, seems like he could've pushed Dooku's ship off the landing pad or something.

Comment: Because they're schmucks

Answer (score 4):

Anakin blew it by being too impulsive. As per usual, Anakin took the fight personal, and for him the obvious and only way to stop Dooku was to take the man down, not do damage to a piece of hardware. And once Anakin engaged, Obi Wan did not have a lot of options (Dooku would not have stood by while Obi Wan demolished the ship).

No idea what was up with Yoda. In the end he preferred to force-catch a humungous pillar that Dooku dropped on the other two in mid-air, instead of pulling two comparatively small bodies aside, and then he did not drop it on the ship, but on the other side. Jedi are repeatedly blamed with arrogance, and maybe there is some truth to it and Yoda just did not take the fight seriously enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Simply put, Dooku was too powerful an enemy to be in the same room with, while trying to accomplish other goals than defending yourself.**

---

The order of events is pretty straightforward. Anakin runs headlong into combat and Obi-Wan follows him in. Anakin gets nerfed almost immediately.

> Like a charging reek, the young Jedi came on, his green lightsaber
> ready to cut Dooku in half. The Count looked at him out of the corner
> of his eye, smiling as if truly amused.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Attack of the Clones - Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novelization))</sup></sub>

Obi-Wan is left to fight Dooku alone, against an enemy with vastly superior combat skill with the lightsaber, and the ability to use Force Lightning on him if he drops his defensive posture for even a moment.

> Obi-Wan stepped slowly at first, then came on in a sudden rush, his blue blade coming in hard, right to left.
>
> But with only a slight movement, the red blade stabbed under the blue, then lifted up, and Obi-Wan’s blade went flying harmlessly high of the mark. With a slight reversal of his wrist, Dooku stabbed straight ahead, and Obi-Wan had to throw himself backward. He brought his lightsaber across as he did, trying to parry, but Dooku had already retracted his blade by then and had settled back into perfect defensive posture.

Anakin turns up again and suffers much the same fate. There was (theoretically) a small opening for him to cripple the ship while Dooku was distracted by killing Obi-Wan, but this is obviously not the ideal time to do so. Note also that there are other vessels in the same hangar, so trashing Dooku's sail-ship wouldn't have actually prevented his escape.

> Hardly pausing, Anakin burst through, lightsaber in hand, entering a huge hangar, with cranes and control panels, **tug-ships** and workbenches.

Yoda turns up and the same scene plays out. Yoda defends against a well-matched enemy, then finally gets distracted because he doesn't want to let Anakin and Obi-Wan die. Dooku makes good his escape. As with the earlier duels, never was there time to go and smash up his ship without leaving an opening for Force-lightning or a quick stab.

> Yoda grabbed the crane and held it fast, but in doing so, he had to release Dooku. The Count wasted no time, sprinting away, leaping up the ramp to his sail ship.